# Data modelling to faciliate pruning/bulk update/delete in scylladb/cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, scylla

Lets say I have a table like below with a composite partition key.

```
CREATE TABLE heartrate (
    pet_chip_id  uuid,
    date text,
    time timestamp,
    heart_rate int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((pet_chip_id, date), time)
);
```

Lets say there is a batch job to prune all the data older than X. I can't do below query since its missing other partition key in the query.

```
DELETE FROM heartrate WHERE date < '2020-01-01';
```

How do you model your data such a way that this can be achieved in Scylla? I understand that internally scylla creates a partition based on partition keys but in this case its impossible to query all the list of `pet_chip_id` and do N queries to delete.

Just wanted to know how people do this outside RDBMS world.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to delete old data automatically in Scylla is using the [Time-to-live](https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/time-to-live/) (TTL) feature:

When you write a row, you add "USING TTL 864000" is you want that data to be deleted automatically in 10 days. You can also specify a default TTL for a given table, so that every piece of data written to the table will get expired after (say) 10 days.

Scylla's TTL feature is separate from the data itself, so it doesn't matter which columns you used as partition keys or clustering keys - in particular the "date" column no longer needs to be a clustering key (or exist at all, for that matter) -  unless you also need it for something else.

Comment: I am aware of Scylla's TTL but the above one is just an example. Lets say in above we have some other text field instead of date then how do we do prune?

Comment: If you have a completely general use case, of going over all items to check "something" to decide what to delete, currently your only choice is to do a **scan** of the entire table, better in parallel from several nodes, to find the rows to delete - and then delete them. Currently neither Scylla nor Cassandra allow "DELETE ... WHERE ... ALLOW FILTERING", nor do they allow paging throw the DELETE that can take a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

As @nadav-harel said in his answer if you can define a TTL that's always the best solution but if you can't, a possible solution is to create a materialized view to be able to list the primary keys of the main table based on the field that you need to use in the delete query. In the prune job you can first do a select from the MV and then delete from the main table using the values that you got from the MV.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    a uuid,
    b text,
    c text,
    d int,
    e timestamp
    PRIMARY KEY ((a, b), c)
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_mv AS
    SELECT a,
           b,
           c
    FROM my_table
    WHERE time IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (b, a, c);
```

Then in your prune job you could select from `my_mv` based on `b` and then delete from `my_table` based on the values returned from the select query.

Note that this solution might not be effective depending on your model and the amount of data you have, but keep in mind that deleting data is also a way of querying your data and your model should be defined based on your queries needs, i.e. before defining your model, you need to think about every way you will query it (including how you will prune your data).